# Cannot access WebExtension `browser` API from within iframe (Firefox)

Tags: iframe, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a cross-browser extension for Chrome/Firefox.

It uses manifest v3 and has following permission granted:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  // ...

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],

  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],

  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  }
```

Out of curiosity, I want to try enclose account registration part of the extension in a `sandbox`-ed `iframe` like so:

```js
<iframe
  className="w-full h-full"
  src={browser.runtime.getURL("my_iframe.html")}
  sandbox="allow-scripts"
/>
```

the `my_iframe.html` pages works normally, sending request to background script, and receive response using `runtime.sendMessage()`.

```js
import browser from "webextension-polyfill";

browser.sendMessage({
  action: "register",
  username: "foo",
  password: "password"
})
```

but when it's in the `iframe`, I got the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined
```

Comment: If you want to embed external content or unsafe script use [sandbox in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/), otherwise there's no need for the sandbox attribute. Either way, the sandboxed document won't have access to chrome/browser API by design, so you'll need to use parent.postMessage inside the iframe to ask the parent to use the API.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot for the explanation, I will take a look on the `manifest.json` config!
The same `iframe` works on Chromium and can access `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` API, I though the same will work on Firefox. 